# Determinar CDN en linea con asp-fallback-test-class

Tags: asp.net-core

deseo implementar asp-fallback-test-class con el link de "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons alguna idea por favor, Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando la siguiente linea de codigo

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" asp-fallback-href="~/font/font.min.css" asp-fallback-test-class="material-icons" asp-fallback-test-property="font-family" asp-fallback-test-value="Material Icons" />
```